# accessing Django models through external Domain

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a project structure as following:
mainFolder

|- djangoFolder

```
     manage.py
     mainApp (package)
```

|- Domain

```
     Facade
     ...
```

mainApp imports Facade

I'm trying to access the ORM features like Model.objects.create(...) from the Facade
but I encountered a few errors when doing so.

I added the following to one of the objects that the Facade holds:

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault(
    "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoFolder.mainApp.settings"
)
django.setup()
```

this change throws : `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant`
which means im calling django.setup() twice in the same context (because mainApp imports Facade)

then I tried removing django.setup() which throws : `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

looked for solutions on the internet/gpt and haven't found one.
any idea how to fix it?

Comment: please post the complete error trace of `...AppRegistryNotReady` exception